# Problema con iteracion de listas python

Tags: python, lista, arraylist

Tengo dos listas:

```
    lista1=[["paco",9],["pepe",9],["luis",10],["paco",10],["luis",9],["mari",9],["pepe",10]]
    lista2=[["luis",10],["mari",9],["mari",6]]
```

quiero recorrer mi lista1 y buscar si se encuntran los elementos de mi lista2, yo hago lo siguiente:

```
    for nombre1,calificacion1 in lista1:
        for nombre2,calificacion2 in lista2:
            if nombre1 == nombre2 and calificacion1 == calificacion2:
                print('Encontrado')
            else:
                print('No encontrado')
```

Salida:

```
    No encontrado
    No encontrado
    No encontrado
    No encontrado
    No encontrado
    No encontrado
    Encontrado
    No encontrado
    No encontrado
    Encontrado 
    ...
```

Lo que yo busco es que solo me de el resultado que tengo en mi lista búsqueda, algo así:

```
    Encontrado
    Encontrado
    No encontrado
```

Comment: No imprimas un valor en cada iteracion... genera una variable que al final de cada iteracion interna te diga si lo encontro o no.. y dependiendo de eso, imprimi el resultado o no....

Comment: Trato de entender pero como harías eso, soy algo nuevo el python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La búsqueda debe tomar cada elemento de `lista2` y revisar si se encuentra en `lista1`.

```
lista1 = [["paco", 9], ["pepe", 9], ["luis", 10], ["paco", 10], ["luis", 9], ["mari", 9], ["pepe", 10]]
lista2 = [["luis", 10], ["mari", 9], ["mari", 6]]

for nombre2, calificacion2 in lista2:
    for nombre1, calificacion1 in lista1:
        if nombre1 == nombre2 and calificacion1 == calificacion2:
            print(nombre1, 'Encontrado')
            break
    else:
        print(nombre1,  'No encontrado')
```

produce:

```
luis Encontrado
mari Encontrado
pepe No encontrado

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Cuando encontramos el nombre en `lista1`, no hay para que seguir buscando: simplemente imprimimos el nombre y usamos `break` para terminar el `for` más interno.

Cuando el nombre no se encuentra en `lista1`, el `for` interno termina normalmente, por lo que se ejecuta el `else`.

Ojo: El `else` está asociado al `for`, no a un `if`. Este `else` no se ejecuta cuando se sale con `break`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!